# Assembly reference issues with WPF Metro Chart

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, reference

So I'm trying to use Torsten Mandelkow `ModernUICharts` NuGet package.
I was able to follow the documentation on his [Codeplex](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/documentation) in a new solution and the chart showed up and populated with no problem. The issue is when I try to do it inside my project I get the error message:

> The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ChartBase'. Line 18 Position 75.

I've ensured that I've copied the code between the two projects exactly multiple times but I keep getting the same result. I've tried looking it up on Stack Overflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315053/modern-ui-metro-charts-wpf-not-showing-up) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443138/type-reference-cannot-find-public-type-named) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627814/type-or-namespace-cannot-be-found-when-reference-does-exist) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665713/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-error-in-xaml)
with no success.

Here is my code:

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="ReqTotalWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style x:Key="MinimalChartStyle" TargetType="chart:ChartBase">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="500"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ReqTotalViewModel:ObservableObject
{ 
    class TestPageViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TestClass> Errors { get; private set; }

        public TestPageViewModel()
        {
            Errors = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
            Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Globalization", Number = 75 });
            Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Features", Number = 2 });
            Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "ContentTypes", Number = 12 });
            Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Correctness", Number = 83 });
            Errors.Add(new TestClass() { Category = "Best Practices", Number = 29 });
        }

        private object selectedItem = null;
        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                // selected item has changed
                selectedItem = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="ReqTotalWPF.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:d="clr-namespace:ReqTotalWPF"
                      Title="ReqTotals" Height="800" Width="963"
                      xmlns:xctk ="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                      xmlns:xcdg ="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
                      xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
                      xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
                      xmlns:metroChart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro">
  <Grid Background="#2F2C38"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
          <metroChart:PieChart
              Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"
              ChartTitle="Minimal Pie Chart"
              ChartSubTitle="Chart with fixed width and height"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
              <metroChart:PieChart.Series>
                  <metroChart:ChartSeries
                      SeriesTitle="Errors"
                      DisplayMember="Category"
                      ValueMember="Number"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}" />
              </metroChart:PieChart.Series>
          </metroChart:PieChart>
      </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ReqTotalViewModel();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure but maybe it will work in your case. Try use change <Style x:Key="MinimalChartStyle" TargetType="chart:ChartBase"> to <Style x:Key="MinimalChartStyle" TargetType="{x:Type chart:ChartBase}">. Also check the output window, there can be another problem.

Comment: Thanks but, that didn't resolve the issue. It did give me an insight of what the problem was when I added it. The output said it was trying to run a framework of 4.0 instead of 4.5 after switching that and correcting this.DataContext = new TestPageViewModel(); pointing at the correct viewmodel. instead of ReqTotalViewModel() (that was inside the MainWindows.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into Project->Application-> Target framework switched it to 4.5.

MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ReqTotalViewModel();

    }
}
```

To

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new TestPageViewModel();

    }
}
```